# JavaScript Loop, subtracting from a total until nothing remains

Tags: javascript, loops, logic

Fellow Stackers,

I am not sure how to make my "bundler" function loop.  I want the ability to pass it different quantities and based on the quantities decide which box/combo is the best match.  Bigger boxes have a bigger discount.  I tried to accomplish this by subtracting how many items came into the bundle vs how many got put into a box and loop through it, but I'm not sure what's wrong with my syntax.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

Ie, 1 item, would go into a 1 Box for $250
Ie. 22 items, would go into two 10 Box, and two 1 Box.
Ie. 39 items, would go into three 10 box, one 5 box, and four 1 Box

```
function product(sku, name, quantity, cost) {
      this.sku = sku;
      this.name = name;
      this.quantity = quantity;
      this.cost = cost;
    }

    function bundler(quantity) {
        var remainder = quantity;
        while (remainder > 0) {
        var bundle = [];
        switch (true) {
        case (quantity >= 10):
          box_10 = new product(3333,"Box of 10",1,1500);
          bundle.push(box_10);
          remainder = quantity - 10;
          return bundle;
        case (remainder >= 5 && remainder <= 9):
          box_5 = new product(2222,"Box of 5",1,1000);
          bundle.push(box_5);
          remainder = remainder - 5;
          return bundle;
        case (remainder <=4 && remainder > 0):
          bundle = new product(1111,"Box of 1",remainder,250);
          remainder = remainder - remainder;
          return bundle;
        }
      }
    }

    var order = bundler(19);
```

Comment: Why not just use modulo division, and Math.floor? Put the types of boxes into an integer array, and loop through its elements. If the Math.floor value is greater than zero, use that many boxes of that size. If the remainder (via modulo) is greater than zero, try the next box size. Store the results into a new integer array.

Comment: @cabbagery, I don't know how to do that.  Perhaps you could post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
function product(sku, name, quantity, cost) {
    this.sku = sku;
    this.name = name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.cost = cost;
}

function bundler(quantity) {
    var remainder = quantity;
    var bundle = [];
    while (remainder > 0) {
        if (remainder >= 10){
            var  box_10 = new product(3333,"Box of 10",1,1500);
            bundle.push(box_10);
            remainder = remainder - 10;
        }
        if (remainder >= 5 && remainder <= 9)
        {
            var  box_5 = new product(2222,"Box of 5",1,1000);
            bundle.push(box_5);
            remainder = remainder - 5;
        }
        if (remainder <=4 && remainder > 0){
            var box_1 = new product(1111,"Box of 1",remainder,250);
            bundle.push(box_1);
            remainder = remainder - 1;
        }
    }
    return bundle;
}

alert(bundler(22).length);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jAa4A/)

Comment: Abhishek, thank you so much!  Comparing your code to mine, looks like I was on the right path, just had some of the logic in the wrong places!